# best way for check one variable to different numbers in JavaScript if statements

Tags: javascript, variables, if-statement

i want check if random variable is equal to some numbers do something

for example i have 16 number that i want check them is equal to random number or not

```
var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (192 - 1+ 1) + 1)
if (randomNum == 1 ||  randomNum == 24 ||  randomNum == 25 ||  randomNum == 48 ||  randomNum == 49 ||  randomNum == 72 ||  randomNum == 73  ||  randomNum == 96 ||  randomNum == 97 ||  randomNum == 120 ||  randomNum == 121 ||  randomNum == 144 ||  randomNum == 145 ||  randomNum == 168 ||  randomNum == 169 )
{
    blnRand=true;
}
else
{
    blnRand=false;
}
```

It's very bad way for check my variable I wanna a short code like this:

```
if (randomNum == 1,24,25,48,49,72,73,96,97,120,121,144,145,168,169)
   blnRand=true;
else
   blnRand=false;
```

but don't work too, how can write short code for the if statement in here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Best" is subjective and depends a lot on how you're using it; you have a few choices:

1. A `switch` statement:

   ```
   switch (randomNum) {
       case 1:
       case 24:
       case 25:
       //...
          blnRand = true;
          break;
       default:
          blnRand = false;
          break;
   }
   ```
2. An array:

   ```
   var answers = [1, 24, 25/*...*/];
   blnRand = answers.indexOf(randomNum) !== -1;
   ```
3. A lookup object:

   ```
   var answers = {
       1: true,
       24: true,
       25: true,
       // ...
   };
   blnRand = answers[randomNum] || false;
   ```
4. A lookup `Set` (ES6 and higher only):

   ```
   var answers = new Set([1, 24, 25/*...*/]);
   blnRand = answers.has(randomNum);
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much @T.J. Crowder, It is very short and powerful answer to my question, of course i think array way is very better than